# Google Analytics API not returning updated profile data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apis-explorer

I have updated property Default URL from `example.com` to `www.example.com` in Google analytics. But while fetching profile data using Analytics API V3, the response is not updated. I.e. I'm still getting `example.com` in API response.

Does it take time to reflect new data in API response and if yes then how much?

Or am I missing some settings?

P.S I tried using Google API Explorer, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

the hostname is provided by the document.location. So if you have sessions on that domain mean that the users are still able to load pages on that domain, this can be pages without redirection or cache versions.